# C++: Inline method shown compilation issue: error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

While compile the below code got compilation error as

> rise.h: error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed (fall->value = id)

While I added the function definition in dot cpp file, got linking error.

**Note:** Its working fine without inline.

File: fall.h

```
#include<rise.h>
class Fall
{
    public:
    char value;
};
```

File: rise.h

```
#include<fall.h>

class Fall;

class Rise
{
    public:
    Fall *fall;

    inline void fill_the_val(struct ring *buf, char flag=false, char id = 0)
    {
        if(true == flag)
        {
            fall->value = id; //this line got compilation issue
        }
    }
};
```

File: rise.cpp

```
#include<fall.h>

#include<rise.h>
int main()
{
   fill_the_val(buf, true, 1);
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the normal circular include dependency problem. The simplest solution is to separate declaration and definition of `fill_the_val`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Yes i have done that earlier. But got linking error, if i separated the declaration and definition. Also if i removed the inline it works.

Comment: @Jarod42 Give more insight please

Comment: @Jarod42: it's under valid scope.

Comment: The problem is that "rise.h" and "fall.h" both `#include` each other. Don't `#include` headers that you don't really need - it looks like "fall.h" does not have any use for "rise.h".

Comment: Linker errors (undefined references or similar) is because you don't build with all source files in your project.

Comment: Linking errors are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).